# Erro ao fazer Build no Jenkins

Tags: maven, deploy, jenkins

Estou com um problema ao configurar a build no jenkins segue erros:

isso acontece na configuração do job " no passo de build", onde escolho a versão do maven e logo abaixo preciso configurar os "goals" porém neste passo não consigo resolver.

Segue imagem do erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você definiu os goals na sua configuração do job?

Comment: @BernardoBotelho consegui arrumar este erro!
ficou assim clean install cargo:deploy
obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Que bom! Você pode responder sua própria pergunta, assim alguém com esse mesmo problema terá mais facilidade em encontrar a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como achei o que eu precisava vou postar aqui para posteriores dúvidas, vou deixar um bonus também porque o plugin do glassfish não pega então usei o cargo haus.

Abaixo segue como ficou configurado meu build:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui segue o trecho de configuração do meu pom.xml com o cargo haus, já que o plugin para o glassfish do jenkins não funciona.

```
<!-- Cargo Code Haus Glassfish -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>glassfish3x</containerId>
                    <type>remote</type>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>runtime</type>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.hostname>localhost</cargo.hostname>
                        <cargo.remote.username>wellington</cargo.remote.username>
                        <cargo.remote.password>wellington</cargo.remote.password>
                        <cargo.remote.port>8080</cargo.remote.port>
                        <cargo.glassfish.domain.name>/Jenkins</cargo.glassfish.domain.name>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <properties>
                            <context>/Jenkins</context>
                        </properties>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.deployment</groupId>
                    <artifactId>deployment-client</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2-b06</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao trabalhar com integração contínua você que é analista de configuração nem sempre terá permissão para alterar o pom.xml dos projetos. Então, a melhor maneira de realizar o deploy dos projetos é usar o plugin do Jenkins que faz este trabalho. A sugestão é que você use o [Deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin). Se precisar, siga [este guia de instalação](http://thiagocolen.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/jenkins-deploy-no-tomcat.html.) do plugin.